# Python: How to treat CSV with text delimiter at the beginning and end of the line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I need the reading of the files to derive to the dataframe, but I didn't find a solution to handle this file format:

[image: Line 12 of CSV]

```
Date,Entity ID,Entity Name,Time,Contacts Recvd Revisado,Contacts Recvd Act,Contacts Handled Sched,Contacts Handled Access%,Contacts Abndn Act,Contacts Abndn Perc,AHT Revisado,AHT Act,Service Level Revisado,Service Level Act,Occupancy Revisado,Occupancy Act,ASA Revisado,ASA Act,Requirements Revisado,Requirements Act,Requirements +/-,Sched Open,Staff Est.,Staff - Req
"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

this is the code i'm using

```
import os    
import glob    
import pandas as pd

path = r'\\Srvflssp03\gto\Planejamento_Operacional\Forecast\2021\11 Novembro\Relatórios MIS'

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '**/*.csv'), recursive=True)

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,quotechar = '"', sep = ',') for f in file_list ])

DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(combined_csv)

DataFrame.head(11)
```

[image: result in python dataframe]

Could anyone tell me what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Please do NOT post data as images.

Comment: you have to read it as normal text, repair line with `" "`, and write all back to file - and later read it as CSV using `read_csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read it as normal text, repair line with `" "`, write all back to file as text, and later read all with `pd.read_csv()` without problems.

---

If you already read it then you may try to repair it. You can get text from first column `Date` and use `io.StringIO` to read it as `csv` to another `DataFrame` - and then you can copy row back to original place.

```
text = '''Date,Entity ID,Entity Name,Time,Contacts Recvd Revisado,Contacts Recvd Act,Contacts Handled Sched,Contacts Handled Access%,Contacts Abndn Act,Contacts Abndn Perc,AHT Revisado,AHT Act,Service Level Revisado,Service Level Act,Occupancy Revisado,Occupancy Act,ASA Revisado,ASA Act,Requirements Revisado,Requirements Act,Requirements +/-,Sched Open,Staff Est.,Staff - Req
"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

# here I use `io` only to simulate file
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
print(df)

# get string from first column (`Date`) in row `0`
line = df.iloc[0]['Date']
print(line)

# convert to new dataframe
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(line), header=None)
print(df2)

# copy back to original dataframe
df.iloc[0] = df2.iloc[0]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
# df - before changes
                                                Date  ...  Staff - Req
0  11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.0...  ...          NaN

[1 rows x 24 columns]

# string `line`
11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,"3,911.69",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00

# df2
        0     1                 2        3     4   ...   19   20   21   22   23
0  11/1/21  2559  AUTORIZACOES BDC  2:30 AM  1.54  ...  0.0  0.0  5.0  0.0  0.0

[1 rows x 24 columns]

# df - after changes
      Date  Entity ID       Entity Name  ... Sched Open  Staff Est.  Staff - Req
0  11/1/21     2559.0  AUTORIZACOES BDC  ...        5.0         0.0          0.0

[1 rows x 24 columns]
```

For your full data it will need to use row `10`

```
line = df.iloc[10]['Date']

# ...

df.iloc[10] = df2.iloc[0]  # `df2` uses `0`
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version with more rows and with `for`-loop

```
text = '''Date,Entity ID,Entity Name,Time,Contacts Recvd Revisado,Contacts Recvd Act,Contacts Handled Sched,Contacts Handled Access%,Contacts Abndn Act,Contacts Abndn Perc,AHT Revisado,AHT Act,Service Level Revisado,Service Level Act,Occupancy Revisado,Occupancy Act,ASA Revisado,ASA Act,Requirements Revisado,Requirements Act,Requirements +/-,Sched Open,Staff Est.,Staff - Req
"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,"3,911.69",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00
"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

# here I use `io` only to simulate file
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # get string from first column (`Date`) in row
    line = row['Date']

    if ',' in line:
        #print(line)

        # convert to new dataframe
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(line), header=None)
        #print(temp_df)
    
        # copy back to original dataframe
        df.iloc[index] = temp_df.iloc[0]
    
print(df)
```

and the same with `apply()` instead of `for`-loop

```
text = '''Date,Entity ID,Entity Name,Time,Contacts Recvd Revisado,Contacts Recvd Act,Contacts Handled Sched,Contacts Handled Access%,Contacts Abndn Act,Contacts Abndn Perc,AHT Revisado,AHT Act,Service Level Revisado,Service Level Act,Occupancy Revisado,Occupancy Act,ASA Revisado,ASA Act,Requirements Revisado,Requirements Act,Requirements +/-,Sched Open,Staff Est.,Staff - Req
"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,"3,911.69",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00
"11/1/21,2559,AUTORIZACOES BDC,2:30 AM,1.54,0.00,60.24,""3,911.69"",0.00,0.00,75,0,100.00,0.00,2.56,0.00,0,0,0.69,0.00,0.00,5.00,0.00,0.00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

# here I use `io` only to simulate file
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
print(df)

def convert(row):
    # get string from first column (`Date`) in row
    line = row['Date']

    if ',' in line:
        # convert to new dataframe
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(line), header=None, names=df.columns)
        #print(temp_df)
    
        # copy back to original dataframe
        row = temp_df.iloc[0]

    return row

df = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
    
print(df)
```

Comment: Fantastic solution!! But is there a way to do this process for every line you find? this process is repeated every time it has a value with a thousand separator and it repeats itself countless times

Comment: if you find all lines with problem and you get `index` of theses lines then you can use `for`-loop to repeate it with different `index` - like `for index in list_of_indexes: line = df.iloc[index]['Date'] ... df.iloc[index] = df2.iloc[0]`